# Can I use a samba share in sources.list?

Tags: apt, samba

I have seen examples of using `http`, `ftp`, and `file` in the `deb` statements in `sources.list`.  Can I use `smb`?   And, where are the options documented? I can't find the right manpage.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
ls -la /usr/lib/apt/methods/
```

will show you the protocols you can use:

```
rinzwind@schijfwereld:~$ ls -la /usr/lib/apt/methods/
total 660
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root   4096 nov 18 07:03 .
drwxr-xr-x 5 root root   4096 nov 18 07:03 ..
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      5 okt 26 13:36 bzip2 -> store
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  34976 okt 26 13:36 cdrom
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  18592 okt 26 13:36 copy
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  18592 okt 26 13:36 file
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  88320 okt 26 13:36 ftp
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  55456 okt 26 13:36 gpgv
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      5 okt 26 13:36 gzip -> store
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 153768 okt 26 13:36 http
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      4 okt 26 13:36 https -> http
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      5 okt 26 13:36 lzma -> store
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 178344 okt 26 13:36 mirror
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  47264 okt 26 13:36 rred
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  30896 okt 26 13:36 rsh
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      3 okt 26 13:36 ssh -> rsh
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  22688 okt 26 13:36 store
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      5 okt 26 13:36 xz -> store
```

"file" might be an option. For "samba" though that would be: no.

There already is a bug report [#231806](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/apt/+bug/231806) on this (from 2008 never got further that triaged).

Comment: Thanks for the link to the bug report. It suggests using cifs and file:, I can probably make that work.

Comment: I tried cifs and file:/, and it works. Only issue I had was on `file:` line, it requires only one slash, eg. `file:/smb/someserver/deb some/path/to/repo/`. Some other tutorials suggest to put more slashes, and it doesn't work.